# Multiple search from HTML table

Tags: java, javascript, html

```js
function doSearch() {
   var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
   var targetTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');
   var targetTableColCount;

   // Loop through table rows.
   for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
      var rowData = '';

      // Get column count from header row.
      if (rowIndex == 0) {
         targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
         continue; //do not execute further code for header row.
      }

      // Process data rows. (rowIndex >= 1)
      for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
         rowData += targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent;
      }

      // If search term is not found in row data then hide the row, else show.
      if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1)
         targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';
      else
         targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
   }
}
```

This code working great for searching one keyword, but I want to search multiple keywords separated by semicolon (;).

Comment: I would say use a regex. 
E.g., x.search(/string1|string2|string3/);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first make your function doSearch with a parameter.
instead of :

```js
function doSearch() {
        var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
```

put

```js
function doSearch(searchValue, rows) {...}
```

Then do

```js
var keywords = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value.split(';');
```

And loop over the function `doSearch(keyword[index], rowIndexes);`

to contain all the keywords

let the function doSearch() return an array with the rowindexes that match.
and pass it to the next call, until all the keywords finish.

the last result will be the rowindexes that match all the keywords.

Comment: If I want to search for 3 keywords (deep;heel;sea) then it will show the search results only for last keyword(sea).

Comment: and it will ignore completely the first 2 keywords ?

Comment: then its as simple as that, instead of `document.getElementById('searchTerm').value` put `var keywords = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value.split(';')`. `var searchText = keywords[keywords.length -1 ]`

Comment: I think you are not getting my question, I want complete filter.
Your answer firstly search for first keyword then in second iteration it will loose the result of first search then will search for second keyword and so on..

Comment: My answer in the comment searches only for the last word. replace it in your code, not mine.

Comment: No your both answers will give the result for only last keyword...I want search result for all keywords...I have tried both of your codes but it's not working.. :